# input type=search not working firefox v24

Tags: html, firefox

I checked http://html5test.com/ and is states that input type=search is supported for FF 24 but it's not working for me.  I'm using < !DOCTYPE html > in my header with the following markup:

```
<input type=search id="search" results=5 placeholder="Search ... " />
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Chrome and Safari work as normal (rounded text field with magnifying glass). FF just renders a normal basic text field, i.e. same as <input type="text">, so it seems to be falling back on type=text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#text-%28type=text%29-state-and-search-state-%28type=search%29):

> Note: The difference between the Text state and the Search state is primarily stylistic: on platforms where search fields are distinguished from regular text fields, the Search state might result in an appearance consistent with the platform's search fields rather than appearing like a regular text field.

What this is saying is that the browser *should* render `search` fields on the page in the same way they are rendered outside the page (ie in the browser toolbar, or elsewhere in the host operating system).

The first point here is that it isn't compulsory. The spec merely says it **might** cause the appearance to change. This means that Firefox is doing nothing wrong by not changing the appearance. The spec doesn't define much else for `search` fields to do, so Firefox can claim to support them without having to do anything special.

And the second point is that if the appearance is changed, that change isn't actually defined in the spec; it is dependent on the platform. This means that you can't rely on the appearance of a `search` field to be consistent across different browsers and operating systems. If you want consistency, style it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the sounds of it, what you are saying is that while ff supports this feature it doesn't have to do anything about it!  I'll style it myself now